# SUMIF with Index and multiple match criteria with Dynamic range

Tags: excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2itf.jpg)

In the above problem, I am trying to create a dashboard of Brands Category wise.
The formula i am trying is.  THis is in google sheets.
=INDEX($A$1:$F6,ArrayFormula(MATCH(A$12&B12,$A$1:$A6&$B$1:$B6,0)),Match(to_text(C$11),$A$2:$F$2,0))

THis returns only 1 value . But I would like to get a sum of BrandA, Catgory1 both in Nos and Pcs. How do I go about doing it? Somehow, not able to work with SUMIF. what is best suited?

Actually trying to create a dashboard for Month wise Sales/Purchase data like the link below. Any better way of doing in?

https://[docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1047uWOrOqkW3L_1hoKh-MaY-O0_CZC0WiqmV8HZqk6o/edit?usp=sharing](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1047uWOrOqkW3L_1hoKh-MaY-O0_CZC0WiqmV8HZqk6o/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

Raj, if I understand your question, the following formula might provide the result you want.

```
=QUERY(Data!A1:F,"select A,B,sum(D),sum(E),sum(F) 
  where A<>'' group by A,B order by A,B 
  label sum(D) 'Apr',sum(E) 'May',sum(F) 'June' ",1)
```

This queries your data, groups it (and sorts) by brand and category (ignoring the Unit type) and sums the values.  It also modifies the header text for the three summed columns.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @kirkg13. This works perfectly . I was trying to create a dashboard with Both sales/ Purchase data. 
 Hence in query i cannot match Apr- Invoices and Purchase. Attached a sample data. Is there any better way to arrive at the dashboard? https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1047uWOrOqkW3L_1hoKh-MaY-O0_CZC0WiqmV8HZqk6o/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Raj, if your sample data is really like that, I'm not sure of the best way to do it.  If your Invoices data was on one tab, and your Purchases data on another tab, it would be easier.  If this is really how your basic data looks, we could do a brute force approach, searching for "Data -Purchase" in column A, and treating all data above that as Sales, and all data in the rows below that as Purchases.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Actually it is in different tabs only. For easy representation, I have brought to a single sheet

Comment: Please share an example sheet with the way your data is structured in the two different tabs.  Otherwise a formula for the data in a single sheet may be totally different from what you require.

Comment: PFA the excel sheet. Since, the raw data is having some sensitive customer info, not able to share the same. Created an extract of the data to work with. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1047uWOrOqkW3L_1hoKh-MaY-O0_CZC0WiqmV8HZqk6o/edit?usp=sharing